# Can't create a hbase table from hive

Tags: hive, hbase

When i can try a create a hbase table from hive I get the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

I want to resolve this problem

Comment: do you have create table permission? What is your DDL look like?

Comment: I have all permission in the table